# How to open a Mega Money Market account without an ssn?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, usd-us-dollar, france, ssn

I am a non resident allien who never went into the United states but who needs to receive usd funds from a United States based company. They requires their suppliers to use their online platform for payments which requires a bank account that accept wire transfers using the us system *(with aba codes)*.

And as the current usd/eur exchange rate is not interesting, I want to keep funds at the new opened account. So I want an interest account that will have higher apy than the reference saving account of my country *(Livret A has 0,75% untaxed apy at all banks nationwide, so I need an interest rate of at least 0,975% apy that will cover the 30% flat tax of my country)*.
It seems Mega money market accounts can provide this, but it seems us banks and credit unions requires a ssn *(not a french ssn)* or an itin. I read I could get an itin by applying a w7 form, but as the funds I ll receive aren t related to trade or business in the United States, I don t know under which exception I should apply for not filling a us tax return.

So is there a way to have an itin without being able to apply for us tax return?

Comment: Are you able to visit the US? It is very difficult to open a US bank account over seas.

Comment: @MichaelC no, I have no plan to spent 800€ for a flight just for opening a bank account. Anyway, this woild be the price of something like 15 years of apy saving.

Comment: Understandable - please see my answer below.

Comment: Something to keep in mind:  I believe that having such an account will make you have to file a US non-resident tax return.

Comment: @LorenPechtel it seems the answer is no https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/aliens-which-income-to-report.

Comment: @MichaelC. Also what is a temporary ITIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxpayer-identification-numbers-tin-s-for-foreign-students-and-scholars):

> Aliens who are not eligible to apply for a U.S. social security
>   number, or who do not meet the Social Security Administration's
>   evidence requirements for an SSN, may apply for an Individual Taxpayer
>   Identification Numbers (ITIN) from the Internal Revenue Service if
>   they have a valid tax reason for needing an ITIN, as explained in the
>   Form W-7 instructions.

Seeing as you don't have a valid **tax** reason for an ITIN, your request will probably be denied by the IRS.

Comment: Why do you say he doesn't have a valid tax reason?  He wants to open an interest-bearing account in the US.

Comment: @LorenPechtel even if I was a resident allien, I would need a signed letter from the bank stating I already opened an interest bearing account. IRS confirmed`We issue ITIN for tax return, we don t issue an ITIN for opening a bank account`

Comment: @Michael I think I found a way for getting an ɪᴛɪɴ. I asked a new question for that https://money.stackexchange.com/q/103700