# I’m a low income non resident alien which don’t fill United States Tax returns. Can I claim to get an ITIN under French tax treaty?

Tags: united-states, legal, france, itin

Let’s be clear. I’m not concerned by any [disposition for the tax treaty](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/france-tax-treaty-documents) nor I can file a tax return and [the real purpose is to open a bank account](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/103670).
But I far I understand, if I claim a benefit [of the treaty](https://www.impots.gouv.fr/portail/files/media/10_conventions/etats-unis/etats-unis_convention-avec-les-etats-unis-impot-sur-le-revenu-impot-sur-la-fortune_fd_1835.pdf) for getting an itin, there are cases where I **don’t have to prove** that I’m concerned by the article number I’m citing. **Isn’t it** (correct me if I’m wrong) ?

So what would be the best article [of the tax treaty to use](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/france-tax-treaty-documents) ? Article 10 or 11 ?
Does the article 24.1 will prevent me from claiming any benefits ?